# N MOSFET bi-directional level shifter draining Vcc possible?

Tags: mosfet, level-shifting

I'm not a specialist in analogue electronics, so my question can be a very simple for someone to answer.

I have a  bi-directional level shifter built with N-channel MOSFET as on picture below. It will pull down HV1 when LV1 pulled down, as HV1 is pulled up via R4 resistor.

My question is: what will happen if HV1 is connected to Vcc, for example +5V? If I pull down LV1, will it result in shortcut with my MOSFET blowing up? If it will result in shortcut what I can do to protect against it? Shall I use a resistor to pull down LV1, so it will limit current flow in case HV1 can't be drained?

Just to clarify, from schematic perspective it will be unknown if HV1 is connected to Vcc, or just pulled up.

[image]

Comment: A series resistor would protect it, but depending on what you want the LV1 side is not the best option cause you could form a voltage divider (could affect low level: way more than 0V for example). Why would you connect a level shifter to VCC though? Are you talking about a possible unintended connection?

Comment: #Wesley Lee: Yes, I need to protect from unintended connection situation. It is I2C protocol over 4 wires, where two wires are for power supply and another two for SCL and SDA. Unfortunately, the way they can be connected is not enforced. I have to use MCU to do the best guess of how wires are connected by passively observing level transition patterns on those 4 wires. Due to potential error in the code, I'm sure there are none :), MCU may pull a wire that is connected to Vcc low. This one will physically damage device, when pulling any other wrong wire low will just corrupt traffic at most.

Comment: It seems to me like you would be better suited asking a question how to solve a specific problem because clearly, the circuit you have shown is unsuitable if the HV1 line is hard-wired to +5V.